# SSIS Flatfile Export fails as SQL agent Job - Filename

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I created an SSIS Package that pulls some rows from a database and writes them into csv Files. 
Since I need a seperate file for each dataset, it is configured with a foreach container and a variable for the filename.
The connection string in the flatfile connection manager ist set as an expression.

The package works fine in Visual Studio, but when exported to SQL Server 2017 and set up as an agent job it fails. The log says the filename is not provided. The error code is 0xC0202010.

Can anybody help?

Comment: My guess is that the file/path that you reference does not exist on the SQL Server for the SQL Agent service account (or the service account does not have access to it). How are you generating the variable?

Comment: its a network share and the agent should have access. In the flatfile connector I use the expression @[User::Directory] +  @[User::Filename] + ".csv"

Comment: Sounds like `@Filename` doesn't have a value when you run it on the server.   But if you don't give us enough information to reproduce the error, the best anybody can do is guess.

Comment: maybe I do have a permission problem. I just tried copying a file to the destination with xp_cmdshell and it's not working. So I have to get that fixed an Monday and hope it solves the entire problem. I will report...